# Returning and accessing array of object of structure in jna

Tags: java, c, jna

I have a structure that contains some char pointers in C:

```
struct inputsheet
{
    char* TestCaseID[MAX_TEST_CASES];
    char*  Description[MAX_TEST_CASES];
};
```

I have a function that is returns array of object of structure:

```
struct inputsheet* getapi(char *docname);
```

Now I want to use this in Java. How can I handle this array of object of structure? I am able to handle a single object but not the array.

For single object my code in C is here:

```
public class str3 extends com.sun.jna.Structure implements com.sun.jna.Structure.ByReference {  
   public Pointer a1;
   public Pointer b2;
   public Pointer c3[]=new Pointer[10];
}
```

Accessing it:

```
str2 s2=CLibrary.INSTANCE.parseid(xmlFile1);
for(Pointer p1:s2.testCaseID) {
    if(p1!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(p1.getString(0));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
\\c code
struct str3{
char *a;
char *b;
char *ab[10];
}

\\jna implementation


package parser;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
public class str3 extends com.sun.jna.Structure implements     com.sun.jna.Structure.ByReference{ 
public Pointer a1;
public Pointer b2;
public Pointer c3[]=new Pointer[10];
}


\\calling it
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
 class ab{
    interface CLibrary extends Library{
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("chardll",
    CLibrary.class);
    str3 getStruct();
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 5;
    str3 a=CLibrary.INSTANCE.getStruct();
    str3[] ab=(str3[])a.toArray(size);
    System.out.println(ab[0].a1.getString(0));          
    }
}
```

It is giving Garbage value as output,, where I have to update my code to get the right output..

Answer (score 2):

From the [javadoc](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/index.html):

> **Returning an Array of struct**
>
> Declare the method as returning a Structure of the appropriate type, then invoke `Structure.toArray(int)` to convert to an array of
>   initialized structures of the appropriate size. Note that your
>   `Structure` class must have a no-args constructor, and you are
>   responsible for freeing the returned memory if applicable in whatever
>   way is appropriate for the called function.
>
> ```
> // Original C code
> struct Display* get_displays(int* pcount);
> void free_displays(struct Display* displays);
>
> // Equivalent JNA mapping
> Display get_displays(IntByReference pcount);
> void free_displays(Display[] displays);
> ...
> IntByReference pcount = new IntByReference();
> Display d = lib.get_displays(pcount);
> Display[] displays = (Display[])d.toArray(pcount.getValue());
> ...
> lib.free_displays(displays);
> ```

**EDIT**

Nominally, your structure would look like this (based on your native definition):

```
class inputsheet extends Structure {
    public Pointer[] TestCaseID = new Pointer[MAX_TEST_CASES];
    public Pointer[] Description = new Pointer[MAX_TEST_CASES];
}

public inputsheet getapi(String docname);

int size = ...; // whatever you do to figure out the size of your returned array 
inputsheet sheet = INSTANCE.getapi("some-doc");
inputsheet[] sheets = (inputsheet[])sheet.toArray(size);
```

If the caller doesn't need to write to the `inputsheet` fields, you should use `String` instead of `Pointer`.

Comment: After using this i am still not able to get the desired result either it is giving me garbage value(in case I use BYREFERENCE),else it is giving NULL Pointer exception (in case of ByValue)

Comment: String can be used when my pointer is const but it is not in my case

Comment: It is incorrect to use `Structure.ByValue`, since your native function returns `struct*`, not `struct`.  You'll need to be a little more explicit about what you've tried; your question references `inputsheet`, `str3`, and `str2`, with no obvious relation between them.

Comment: Actually Input sheet is used in my main project, I was just trying to implement a dummy first, 
In that str3 is my Structure,

Comment: How is your native code returning an "array of struct"?  According to your spec, the returned pointer must be a heap-allocated block of size `N*sizeof(str3)`, where `N` is the number of structures.

Comment: my native code is returning pointer to the array of struct,
    struct nit a[6];
    return a;

Comment: That's stack-allocated memory, which is invalid as soon as your function returns.  Do `malloc(6*sizeof(struct nit))` instead.

Comment: Hey Its done some problem was dere related to scope ,,the struct array that i was returning was not in Global scope .