# Returning struct from java callback to c++

Tags: java, c++, jna

In my software application I am using a native library in C++ from Java using JNA. I need a callback function that returns a complex java object to C++.

This might be a simple problem, but I have no experience with C++ or JNA, and I am unable to successfully return the java object to C++.

Most examples I have come across for JNA callback functions are simple, and either they don't return anything or return a simple native type.

My native code looks like the following

```
typedef const char* SMC_String;
int doNativeProcessing(SMC_String identifier, SMC_String lastName, SMC_String firstName)

typedef struct SimpleStruct
{
  int myInt;
  SMC_String myString;
} SimpleStruct;

typedef SimpleStruct* (*GetSimpleStruct_Callback)(SMC_String identifier);
...

// function that gets called from Java
int doNativeProcessing(SMC_String identifier, SMC_String lastName, SMC_String firstName)
{
  cout << "In native function" << endl;
  ...do some processing...
  callMyCallback();
  return 0;
}

// function that calls the callback 
void callMyCallback()
{
  SimpleStruct *retSimpleStruct = GetSimpleStruct_Callback("id");
  cout << "returned int: " << retSimpleStruct->myInt << endl;
  cout << "returned string: " << retSimpleStruct->myString << endl;
}
```

Java code:

```
public class SimpleStruct extends Structure {
  public static class ByReference extends SimpleStruct implements Structure.ByReference
  {}

  public SimpleStruct() {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("myInt", "myString");
  }

  public int myInt;
  public String myString;
}
...
public class GetSimpleStructCB implements Callback {
    public SimpleStruct.ByReference callback(final String requestId) {
      System.out.println("In Java callback");

      final SimpleStruct.ByReference retVal = new SimpleStruct.ByReference();
      retVal.myInt = 25;
      retVal.myString = "Hello World!";
      return retVal;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    nativeLibrary = (NativeLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("my_native_dll", NativeLibrary.class);
    nativeLibrary.doNativeProcessing("id", "Doe", "John");
}
```

When I run the application, the output is

```
In native function
In Java callback
returned int: 0  
returned string: <blank value>
```

instead of the expected

```
In native function
In Java callback
returned int: 25  
returned string: Hello World!
```

Could you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Your help is much appreciated.

Regards,
H.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15430260/1531971

Comment: Post some real code - that C++ sample isn't C++.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I tried to simplify the code here in order to not clutter the post. My Java callback does get called, and I have verified it via log statements.

Should I post the all the code from loading the library in Java as well as the C++ function that gets called from Java?

Comment: There is simplify, and then just plain wrong - for example, `SimpleStruct[] mySimpleStructs;` is not valid C++, and it wouldn't be if it were rearranged.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have cleaned it up.

Comment: @jdv The post you referenced is returning the struct from C++ to Java. I want to return a struct from Java callback to C++.

Comment: My point is that that JNA uses Pointer and Structure for interchange of non-primitive types.

Comment: You'd be better off having the native code pass a struct* to the callback, then have the callback fill in the struct contents as needed.  That way there's no confusion about who owns the memory, and JNA will automatically sync the Java Structure to the native struct memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each JNA `Structure` allocates its own memory, which may be GC'd as soon as it goes out of scope.

You need to either have your native code pass the memory to the Java code to be populated (rather than allocating one and returning it), or keep a strong reference to *every* `Structure` that is returned from the Java code to prevent GC.

You might also try calling `Structure.write()` just before return; normally Java synchs structures automatically, but there may be a bug doing so when returning a Structure from a callback.

Comment: I passed reference to the struct in the callback and was able to get the values as expected back in the native code. Thanks very much for your help.